# How to check if game center is same account as iCloud

Tags: ios, game-center

So lets say person A and person B each have their own apple id that has a game center and iCloud. So for a game person A is signed in as person a's game center and iCloud. So for a game I'd save the data in iCloud and achievements in their game center. But what if the user (for whatever reason) signs in as person B in game center but is still signed in as themselves (person A) in iCloud. Is there a way I can detect that and not give person B person a's achievements? Or vice versa if person a remains signed into game center but person B's iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API access to iCloud or Game Center login info. (Probably for security/privacy reasons? Good idea if you ask me.) Without such access I don't see a way you could correlate the two. (Which is probably also a privacy win, even if it blocks your use case.)

As of iOS 8 there's less reason to worry about this, though: you can save game state to a Game Center ID with the new [`GKSavedGame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSavedGame_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKSavedGame) API.

Prior to iOS 8, I suppose you could write the [`playerID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/playerID) of the local player in your saved game data, but that won't help you if the save-game files change out from under you due to an iCloud login change, or if the `playerID` itself changes. (I'm not sure Apple guarantees how long an ID persists.)